# isDisplayed, isEnabled, isSelected method available in Java script for shodow dom elements in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

**Selenium Version:** 4.0.0

Is there a way to implement isDisplayed, isEnabled, isSelected Methods in Selenium using Java script for shadow dom elements?

I tried these similar steps below but apparently not worked. Any guidance please?

Code:

```
   public void isEnabledUsingJavaScript() {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    Boolean test= (Boolean) js.executeScript("document.querySelector("foo >boo").shadowRoot.querySelector("foo>boo>span").enable()");
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

**Note:** Since it is a **showdow dom**, the usual XPATH or CSS selectors cannot be applied.

**Error:-**

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: document.querySelector(...).shadowRoot.querySelector(...).enable is not a function
```

While I understand the error, not sure which appropriate method exists in java script to use in these kind of scenarios.

Comment: Why dont you take the variable as a webelement and then use the normal methods?

Comment: @QualityMatters As I specified, the normal way of identifying using XPATH or CSS will not work due to shadow dom implementation.

Comment: In which language you are looking the solution? Java? as you have used sysout

Comment: @QualityMatters: I am using both java and javascript to handle shodowdom in selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to typecast the `variable` returned to `webElement`, Then you will be able to perform all operation which can be done in a `webElement`.

For your reference, below is a website `(https://www.studydrive.net)`, where `Accept cookie button` appears under a `shadow root`, which with the help of java script executor, can be fetched from page and type casted to `web element`.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.studydrive.net/") ;
driver.manage().window().maximize();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Thread.sleep(30);
WebElement element = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector('#uc-center-container > div.sc-jcVcSv.gBDztr > div > div.sc-giImIA.jqkmtR > div > button.sc-gsTEea.ffHglG')");

if(element.isDisplayed()) {
System.out.println("element is displayed");
element.click();
System.out.println("element is clicked");
} else {
 System.out.println("element is not visible");
}
```

**Output:**

```
element is displayed
element is clicked
```

Comment: I have learned few new stuffs from you. Appreciated!!!